# Prove $\mathcal{L}^1$ is a vector space

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mathcal{L}^1$ be the space of all Lebesgue integrable functions, that is $f\in \mathcal{L}^1$ is measurable and $\int f^+d\mu,\int f^-d\mu<\infty$.

Show that this is a vector space , I know all I need to show is that for $f,g\in \mathcal{L}^1$ and $a,b\in \mathbb R$:

$af+bg\in \mathcal{L}^1$

So:

$$\int (af+bg)d\mu=a\int fd\mu +b\int gd\mu=a\int f^+d\mu -a\int f^- d\mu+b\int g^+d\mu-b\int g^-d\mu=\int(af^++bg^+)d\mu-\int(af^-+bg^-)d\mu \leq\left|\int(af^++bg^+)d\mu+\int(af^-+bg^-)d\mu\right|$$

And here is where I am stuck.

How do I go on from here, If it is a good direction? If not what is?

Comment: And now, the triangle inequality (or a small variant)

Comment: I am failing to see how I apply the triangle inequality here due to the minus sign.

Comment: $f-g \leq |f + g|$ is a variation of the triangle inequality.

Comment: ok. I have applied the triangle inequality but don't I need to show $\int |(af+bg)|d\mu\leq \infty$? I still fail to see how to show that? how do I turn all the $f^+,g^+,f^-,g^-$ terms back into $f$ and $g$ now that I don't have a minus sign?

Comment: You never needed to expand it at all, see the answer below for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $ f\in \mathcal{L}^1$ if

$$\int |f|d\mu <\infty .$$

Let $f,g\in \mathcal{L}^1$ and $a,b\in \mathbb R$, thus $af+bg\in \mathcal{L}^1$ if $\displaystyle\int |af+bg|d\mu<\infty$, so
$$\int |af+bg| d\mu < \int (|af|+|bg|)d\mu=\int|af|d\mu+\int|bg|d\mu=|a|\int|f|d\mu+|b|\int|g|d\mu <\infty,$$ since $f,g\in \mathcal{L}^1$.